# Pokemon Go Not Working On "free wifi"

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm on adroid and my game works great when I'm on my home wifi or using my cellular data.  However, since my data package is rather limited, I try to play mostly using wifi. The problem with this is that when I go somewhere with free wifi, it doesn't work. My phone shows that the wifi signal is actually stronger than I have at home wandering around my back yard and street (where it works just fine), but it still won't connect and let me play.

Thoughts?

Comment: A lot of public wifi networks have no password, but then require you to log in or do something else in order to connect to the internet. Generally visiting any page in your default browser will trigger a redirect to the log in page.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possibilities. The first possibility is that the internet connection is just really really crappy. You can check if this is the case by simply browsing the internet and see if that loads fast enough. The second possibility which I think is maybe more likely is that the provider of the wifi spot simply blocks any requests to the pokemon servers. This is much like how  for example porn filters work. They can just restrict what you can access